# Undefined index on cURL request on Graph API

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm using Facebook's graph API to retrieve some data via a cURL call in PHP and I'm receiving an Undefined index error and I don't know how to target it correctly.

**cURL Request**:

```
<?php
/* Call the cURL request to pull in Instagram images */
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/". get_option('insta_id') ."/media?fields=media_url,permalink,username,media_type,thumbnail_url&access_token=". get_option('insta_accesstoken'));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$array = json_decode($result, true);
?>
```

**Array mapping**:

```
<?php
/* Loop through the array and only pull API fields */
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
        'permalink' => $entry['permalink'],
        'username' => $entry['username'],
        'media_type' => $entry['media_type'],
        'thumbnail_url' => $entry['thumbnail_url']
    ];
}, $array['data']);
?>
```

Via the Graph API, some have the thumbnail_url and some don't as shown below:
[image]

I am receiving an debug error as below:
[image]

Comment: Just check that it exists (or isn't empty) when you assign it, e.g.: `'thumbnail_url' => !empty($entry['thumbnail_url']) ? $entry['thumbnail_url'] : ""`

Comment: Works like a charm - Post as an answer so I can choose as best answer - @CD001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer was `'thumbnail_url' => !empty($entry['thumbnail_url']) ? $entry['thumbnail_url'] : ""` by @CD001.